# undefined local variable or method `permitted_task_attributes’ for #<Api::V1::TasksController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, ruby-on-rails-6, solidus, spree-auth-devise

I have a solution that follows the paradigm of Spree/Solidus, which encapsulate permitted params. It is not in my power to change it but to follow suit. However, I am having a problem I cant reproduce which is undefined local variable or method `permitted_task_attributes’ for #Api::V1::TasksController:0x0000000000b7c0.

Below is the code:

**controller/api/v1/task_controller.rb**

```
module Api
  module V1
    class TasksController < ApiController
      def index
        task = Task.all
        render json: task
      end

      def create
        task = Task.create!(create_action_params)
        if task
          render json: task
        else
          render json: task.errors
        end
      end

      private

      def create_action_params
        params.require(:task).permit(permitted_task_attributes) # The problem is with this variable `permitted_task_attributes`
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**controller/api_controller.rb**

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_api_request

  private

  def set_api_request
    request.format = request.format == :xml ? :xml : :json
  end
end
```

li**b/controller_helpers/strong_parameters.rb**

```
module ControllerHelpers
  module StrongParameters
    def permitted_attributes
      PermittedAttributes
    end

    delegate(*PermittedAttributes::ATTRIBUTES,
             to: :permitted_attributes,
             prefix: :permitted)

    def permitted_task_attributes
      permitted_attributes.task_attributes
    end
  end
end
```

**lib/permitted_atrributes.rb**

```
module PermittedAttributes
  ATTRIBUTES = [
    :task_attributes
  ].freeze

  mattr_reader(*ATTRIBUTES)

  @@task_attributes = [
    :avatar_url, :description, :recorded_on
  ]
end
```

**Error**

```
undefined local variable or method `permitted_task_attributes’ for #<Api::V1::TasksController:0x0000000000b7c0>
```

I do understand the controller do not have access to this method called `permitted_task_attributes` but I couldn't fix it. I have tried to include `ControllerHelpers::StrongParameters` in the controller and I still have uninitialized constant error. How can I fix this?

Comment: `/lib`has not been included in the autoload paths since Rails 3 or something like that. Either require the file or place it in `/app` which is autoloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have moved **strong_parameters.rb** out of `/lib` and moved it to controller concerns. I alos moved **permitted_atrributes.rb** out of `/lib` directory too. I then include  **strong_parameters.rb** in the tasks_controller.rb e.g. `include StrongParameters`.

The problem is that the controller didn't recognize the `permitted_task_attributes` method in the **strong_parameters.rb** and it throws an error.